# Tkinter: Change Label when OptionMenu selection changes

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having trouble updating a label based on a selection from an option menu. Below is a working example of my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

secs = ['Subject', 'Difficulty', 'Percent', 'Grade', 'Pass']

master = Tk()
v = StringVar(master)
v.set(secs[0])
def on_option_change(event):
    #lab2.destroy()
    lab2 = tk.Label(master, text=v.get())
    lab2.grid(row=2, column=1)
w = OptionMenu(master, v, *secs, command=on_option_change)
w.grid(row=1, column=0)
lab1 = tk.Label(master, text='Current value:')
lab1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
lab2 = tk.Label(master, text=secs[0])
lab2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
mainloop()
```

The issue is that the old label remains behind the new one when a new option is selected. However, when I add code to destroy the old label, I, understandably, get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lab2' referenced before assignment
```

Any suggestions on an easy fix would be most appreciated. I am rather novice with Tkinter and GUI creation in general. And I have been searching for an answer for several hours, to little avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the lab2 variable global by writing this "global lab2" inside the on_option_change function at the first line.

Comment: Great! Thanks! If it is simple enough, could you explain why that worked, for my learning?